# GET and POST method on one single View

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I wonder if is possible to have GET and POST method on the same view/form or they should be separated on two views? Also, can I have two models(`IEnumerable`, `Generic`,...) on one view?

Controller

```
public class MyController : Controller
   {

     public ActionResult GetView()
      {
          return View();
      }


        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult PostView()
        {

            return View();
        }


        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult PostView()
        {
                        return View();
        }
    }
```

View

```
@model IEnumerable<AppName.Models.OneClass>
@using AppName.Models


@using (Html.BeginForm("GetView", "MyController", FormMethod.Get))
{some code}

@using (Html.BeginForm("PostView", "MyController", FormMethod.Post))
{some code}
```

Is this possible?

Comment: In the controller, yes. In the view - well having 2 forms is OK, but why not use some ajax to communicate with the controller?

Comment: Ok. I did not think about ajax, I am not familiar with that language. thx

Answer (score 0):

You can have multiple forms on one view, yes.

Separate models, you can do that too.

Imagine you have Model1 and Model2 and you want to use them each for a different form.

You create a third wrapper model Model3 where Model1 and 2 become simple properties for example and then use each one for its own form / partial view, whatever.

Your model would look like this:

```
public class WrapperModel {
    public Form1Model model1 { get; set; }
    public Form2Model model2 { get; set; }
}
```

then your form 1 uses WrapperModel.model1 and the other uses the second model. This is quite common when you have scenarios like this.

You could use some partial views for your forms for example and specify the different model in each one. This would at least allow some separation between them.